# What game is this a screenshot of?

Tags: game-identification

[image]

It looks like an SNES-era RPG. Originally from the [libGDX docs page](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/HowtoNinePatch) (an example of nine-patching a sprite).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The game is [Ara Fell (Google image search)](https://www.google.fr/search?q=RPG+ara+fell&rlz=1C1CHFX_frFR550FR550&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=xTLKU_jOBfGR0QWq_4DIDA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=955), an indie RPG developed with [RPG makers](http://rpgmaker.net/games/12/). Although it was still in development at the time this answer was written, the game has now been [released](https://stegosoftgames.itch.io/ara-fell).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the game is cancelled, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Yes it appears so =(

Comment: Looks released now: https://stegosoftgames.itch.io/ara-fell